# How does the Kurgan's sword work?

Tags: highlander, highlander-franchise

In the first *Highlander* movie, we see the Kurgan in a hotel room assembling his sword.  It was a bunch of segments that fit neatly together like something you would buy at an IKEA for weapons (IKILLYA?).  Even the blade came in multiple segments.

From what I understand, a blade needs to have a certain amount of give.  Like a highway, it needs to be able to deal with a certain level of fluctuation and bending, otherwise it would just break when meeting substantial resistance.  Now the reason why highways are not made of interlocking segments is because the bending and fluctuation would not all happen in the same direction and the segments would push against each other resulting in warping and deformation.  We can expect the same problem from a sword that has a segmented blade.

I am aware of other segmented blades in fiction (Ivy's sword in *SoulCalibur* and Renji's Zanpakutto in *Bleach*), but those are less swords and more bladed whips.  The Kurgan's sword operates purely as a standard bastard sword, so how does his blade not break on impact?

Comment: This is a textbook example of [Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool) (warning: TVTropes link). There is no reason for it to work, but it makes for a cool scene; so for purposes of the film, it works. (Also, just because something was in SoulCalibur doesn't make it realistic...)

Comment: Most things in SoulCalibur are unrealistic.  It's spelling is very unrealistic.

Comment: On behalf of Paul D.Waite, "Very well, Thank you"

Comment: MAGNETISM! Or he hadn't discovered the flesh sheath the immortals used in the TV series :)

Comment: @JasonK but how do magnets work?

Comment: On behalf of immature men like me: "Ask your mum"!

Comment: @MagikarpMaster I dunno, I always just assumed the kurgan blade had a primitive electromagnet in the hilt that held all the blade pieces together since just a friction fit wouldn't work.

Comment: Most things in SoulCalibur are just unrealistic.  Ivy's attributes besides the sword are *unbelievable*, and amusingly animated :)

Comment: A sword needs flexibility *unless that sword is huge,* in which case the structure is solid enough.  The flexibility part is needed to make swords as light as possible for regular sized people, where Kurgan just doesn't care how much it weighs.

Comment: I want to give you points just for IKILLYA

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It would likely work badly. Skallagrim goes into it in more detail here:

The quillons are too thick, the blade is too heavy, the pop-out bits would likely break under anything heavier than a rapier, and indeed, the bits that snap together would likely fall apart with any real pressure.

That said, the *Highlander* wiki has an (unsourced as best I can tell) explanation, that [the blade we see being assembled is a "practice blade"](https://highlander.fandom.com/wiki/The_Kurgan#Fighting_Style):

> The Kurgan fought with an emphasis on strength and brute striking-power, usually attempting to end the fight before it began with a single surprise attack. He would stalk his opponents methodically until he was ready. Then, he would attack without even so much as a challenge. He used a special two-handed broadsword, which he eventually supplemented with a detailed replica that could be disassembled and packed away as needed for practice in situations where the original could not be smuggled in and had to remain hidden, usually in his vehicle.
>
> That the two blades are not seen together does not undermine the logic and resourcefulness of having a practice blade, that while not strong enough to last very long in combat, would give The Kurgan time to get to the original. It also recognizes the cunning and survival instincts of The Kurgan, adapting to the need for discretion in modern times while keeping his skills at their peak.

Comment: There's zero indication in the script or the film that the sword is anything other than the Kurgan's primary weapon

Comment: In any case, I've found my new favourite youtube channel.  Thanks Fuzzy

Comment: @MagikarpMaster If you liked Skallagrim, you will like 
scholagladiatoria and Lindybeige even better.

Comment: Love Lindybeige.  He is my spirit animal

Comment: Nice try, that wiki explanation, but “The Kurgan, adapting to the need for discretion…”—they must have seen a different movie. Also the description of the fighting style might resemble his last fight of the movie, but not the other two.

Comment: @Valorum I like the Highlander wiki explanation - it makes sense. By sheer willpower, can't we make this explanation canon? Everyone has to agree. There can be no holdout naysayers like Valorum or the magic won't work. :-)

Comment: @RobertF - I've removed the unsupported bit from the wiki. All the evidence (including the consistent use of the same prop throughout the film) would indicate that it's not a replica or a training blade, it's the same sword.

Answer (score 25):

One of the key conceits in Highlander (ignoring wackiness we see in the sequel) is that the immortals have access to weapons technology that simply *defies* modern understanding of metallurgy; swords that are near-infinitely sharp, unbelievably durable and inconceivably resilient. Connor, for example has been using Ramirez' samurai sword **to duel with** for nearly 500 years (and he for 1500 years before that) yet it remains in *defiantly* mint condition when it should have been sharpened down to [a nub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i616T.jpg).

> JUAN RAMIREZ
> climbing the trail to the forge. Olive skin, hawk nose, twinkling
> eyes, flashing teeth. Flintlock pistol in his belt, crossbow across
> his back.
>
> Strapped to his side, **a Samurai sword, carved hand-guard,
> razor-sharp, feather-light.**
>
> <sub><sup>[*Highlander*: Final Draft Script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Highlander_final.txt)</sup></sub>

and

> **MACLEOD:** *This was forged in 593 B.C. Metal folded over 200 times.*
>
> He enjoys her amazement.
>
> **MACLEOD:** (continuing gently) *Like finding a 747 a thousand years before the Wright Brothers flew. Right?*
>
> <sub><sup>[*Highlander*: Final Draft Script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/Highlander_final.txt)</sup></sub>

The Kurgan's sword is likely a product of the aforementioned weapons wizardry. It doesn't break simply because it's made of durable metals.

Comment: Your answer is indeed excellent, but how would you account for Connor's blade shattering in the third movie (technically the second movie since "the quickening" was just a collective fever dream)?

Comment: @MagikarpMaster - Dunno. Possibly worthy of its own question.

Comment: Feather-light sword? That would make for a really bad weapon.

Comment: @charlie_pl - It only needs to be heavy if it's not sharp.

Comment: @charlie_pl To our understanding perhaps. Don't make the mistake of judging things from other worlds by our standards, they might have access to materials or techniques that we don't or there may be factors at play that we are not aware of. Here, it's probably just the rule of cool put in practice but it never hurts to keep an open mind.

Comment: It is worth noting that Connor's katana (The one he got from Juan) was not made by an immortal.  It was made by Ramirez's father in law, the emperor of Japan.

Comment: @Magikarp - it was a gift from him. I don't believe he actually made it himself

Comment: @Valorum I stand corrected.

Comment: `ignoring wackiness we see in the sequel` Sequel?  There was no sequel!

Comment: @Beofett - Keep telling yourself that

Comment: There Can Be Only One....real highlander movie :)  @charlie_pl swords throughout history rarely weighed more than a kilo and a half.  Even 2 handers didn't weigh more than 2 kilos. They were still amazingly good at cutting things up. http://www.thearma.org/essays/weights.htm#.WXI1j_n48ow

Comment: How was Conor dueling with Ramirez' sword for more than 1,000 years? Conor was born in 1518. Ramirez died in 1542 and the latest we've seen Conor alive (assuming everything is canon) is 2004 in Endgame. He used Ramirez blade for 462 years at most.

Comment: @geewhiz - `and he for 1500 years before that` where the "he" in this clause refers to Ramirez.

Comment: @MattJones Valorum fixed it

Comment: It's fine though, because they were aliens right? *sobs into pillow*

Answer (score 2):

I have always thought that Kurgans blade would have some sort of hollow locking mechanism that would extend a barbed rod from the hilt, further up the blade, and then lock into place pulling the 2 blade sections tightly together.  It's the only way I could get my head around the thought that the little stub depicted would cause the top half of the sword spinning off to impale an innocent bystander 20 meters away the first time he crossed swords with anyone.

Even my purely imaginary mechanism still wouldn't hold up to actual combat.  the weight and leverage on the joint make it impossible.

That just leaves The Rule of Cool or unsubstantiated theories.  Maybe Candy was an Elvish sorceress in a mini skirt who repaired the broken blade in Kurgan's hotel room.  It's as valid as any other theory.

Comment: Can you provide sources for your answer?

Comment: @Edlothiad hmm, sources....see "purely imaginary", rule of cool, or unsubstantiated theories.  this is just imagination at work.  As far as the physics involved: Try chopping firewood with a splitting maul that has a 4 pound head and a  cracked handle.  That will demonstrate the physics involved with swinging a long, straight object of similar weight with a weak point along the shaft.  Source:  the damage caused to my fence in my back yard.  luckily, no one was hurt.  yeah, I know a splitting maul is not a sword, but I'm not a massive iron age swordsman.  I simply assume the forces are similar

Comment: And there are some mild parallels with how we use pins to set bones and when fixing shafts.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots true.  Although when using pins to set bones it's generally there to hold the bones in place until the body can fuse them back together with calcium.  Sometimes they are left to add strength, because the fused seam may or may not be as strong as the original smooth bone.  Point being, the seam is filled in with the original material.   There could be a parallel  with the sword, but you would have to weld the ends of the sword.  kind of impractical in a flop house like the Kurgan was staying in

Answer (score 1):

It's established that the immortals of *Highlander* have the ability to send their consciousness into the mind of an animal. It's not much of a stretch to believe that they put some of their life force into their swords, especially during a duel. That also explains the showers of sparks that often appear when their swords cross (although they needed cables and car batteries in the movies).

In a sense, then, the swords are alive, even magical, when wielded by an immortal. They carry a portion of the Prize. They heal their wounds. They cut through anything. They kill beings who cannot die.

Comment: If what you say is true, then why did Connor not die when his sword shattered in the third movie?